# how can use hhvm on opensuse?

Tags: php, compilation, opensuse, hhvm

my server is opensuse 13.1 terminal
and I want to use hhvm3 but there is nothing about how to compile hhvm on opensuse in hhvm github and hhvm website

Are there some people use hhvm on opensuse successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 64-bit openSUSE 13.1, try this:

https://software.opensuse.org/package/hhvm?search_term=hhvm

... then click "Show unstable packages"

Comment: I want to know how can i compile hhvm on opensuse 13.1 of later.
Is this rpm package compiled by you?

Comment: Not compiled by me.  That openSUSE OBS user repo appears to be owned by Martijn Goedhart (smarty12). If you don't want to use his RPM, you can try your luck at compiling. On that OBS page under 13.1, show unstable packages, and there should be a link to download a source RPM.  Another promising option would be to go to the hhvm page itself to download the source. They don't appear to have a SUSE howto, but this one for Fedora looks generic enough (git, cmake, make): https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Fedora-19-or-20 Please comment back & upvote if this works.